# Create a non square full-rank matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a non square N-ranked matrix (named `A`) with M column and N rows. (N>M)

How can I do it in Matlab?

Comment: I edited the question, the previous one was wrong

Comment: contradictory title. full rank matrix would be rank M in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a matrix does not exist, the maximum possible rank in your case is `M` [[reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties)]. MATLAB can not create such a matrix.